# Auto Hotkey Script for scrolling

Tags: autohotkey

So im not that farmiliar with Auto Hotkey but i would like somone to help me writing a script that scrolls the mouse wheel up every second and is triggered by holding down a specific key.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
F1::
    while GetKeyState("F1", "P") ; while holding down F1
    {
        SendInput, {WheelDown}   ; send this command to the active window
        Sleep, 1000              ; every second (1000 ms)
    }
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/While.htm

Comment: Modify the above code to fill your needs. [It's very easy](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#mouse-wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Adapted Relax's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60966971/5282788) to my own needs -

In AutoHotKey v1

```
; Autoexecute
; Add below code to the top of your script
; Add more apps with GroupAdd to enable auto-scroll

GroupAdd, AutoScroll, ahk_class SUMATRA_PDF_FRAME       ; Sumatra
GroupAdd, AutoScroll, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1      ; hakuneko.exe

; Add below code anywhere in your script after Autoexecute

#If WinActive("ahk_group AutoScroll")

^+s::   ; CTRL + SHIFT + s keys
Progress, b w200 x1650 y985 ctWhite cwBlack zh0 fs9 ws1000 fm9,• Scrolling •,,,Arial
loop {      ; can release Shift and S keys once loop starts
    send {down 3}
    sleep 100
    KeyWait, Shift, d t0    ; press Shift to scroll faster
    if (ErrorLevel = 1) {
        sleep 200
    }
    KeyWait, CTRL, d t0     ; release CTRL key to break out of the loop
    if (ErrorLevel = 1) {
        Progress, Off
        break
        }
}
return

#If
```

In AHK v2

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance force
KeyHistory 500

; Autoexecute
; Add below code to the top of your script
; Add more apps with GroupAdd to enable auto-scroll

GroupAdd "AutoScroll", "ahk_class SUMATRA_PDF_FRAME"       ; Sumatra
GroupAdd "AutoScroll", "ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1"      ; hakuneko.exe

; Add below code anywhere in your script after Autoexecute

#HotIf WinActive("ahk_group AutoScroll")

^+s:: {   ; CTRL + SHIFT + s ; sleep notifications
MyNotificationFunc("• Scrolling •", "200", "1650", "985", "0")
loop {      ; can release Shift and S keys once loop starts
    send "{down}"
    MyNotificationFunc("• Scrolling •", "30", "1650", "985", "0")
    if !(KeyWait("Shift", "d t0") = 1) { ; press Shift to scroll faster
        MyNotificationFunc("• Scrolling •", "200", "1650", "985", "0")
        ; increase parameter 200 (milliseconds) to slow down
        ; if notification is annoying, replace with "Sleep 200" (without quotes)
        }
    if !(KeyWait("CTRL", "d t0") = 1) ; release CTRL key to break out of the loop
        break
    }
}

#HotIf

; replace Progress command from AHK v1 with GUI in AHK v2
MyNotificationFunc(mytext, myduration, xAxis, yAxis, timer) {
Global MyNotification := Gui()
MyNotification.Opt("+AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow")  ; +ToolWindow avoids a taskbar button and an alt-tab menu item.
MyNotification.BackColor := "EEEEEE"  ; White background, Can be any RGB color (it will be made transparent below).
MyNotification.SetFont("s9 w1000", "Arial")  ; font size 9, bold
MyNotification.Add("Text", "cBlack w181 Left", mytext)  ; black text, show progress text
MyNotification.Show("x1650 y985 NoActivate")  ; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window
WinMove xAxis, yAxis,,, MyNotification
if timer = 1
    SetTimer EndMyNotif, myduration * -1
if timer = 0 {
    Sleep myduration
    EndMyNotif
    }
}

EndMyNotif() {
MyNotification.Destroy
}
```